# Cannot find Grpc.Tools reference in C# project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, grpc

I am not understanding how to use this NuGet package manager in Visual Studio 2019

I installed the Grpc.Tools package from Nuget package manager.

I clicked the checkbox next to the package on solution,
But it shows there is no reference to

`using Grpc.Core;`

I dont see Grpc.Core under references anywhere,

And when I searched the references I could not find GRPC anywhere

Am I missing something, is there another step to installation?

[image]

[image]

My code is simple, its below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Grpc.Core;

namespace gRPCtest
{
    public class Server : Form
    {
        public Server()
        {
            Text = "Server Window";
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
        }
    }
    public class Client : Form
    {
        public Client()
        {
            Text = "Client Window";
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 200);
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the child window
            Server serverForm = new Server();
            serverForm.Show();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the child window
            Client clientForm = new Client();
            clientForm.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

In the terminal I tried running the following commands and got errors:

```
PS C:\Users\Waymo\Desktop\prf.net\gRPCtest> NuGet\Install-Package Grpc.Core
NuGet\Install-Package : The module 'NuGet' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module NuGet'.
At line:1 char:1
+ NuGet\Install-Package Grpc.Core
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (NuGet\Install-Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule
PS C:\Users\Waymo\Desktop\prf.net\gRPCtest> Import-Module NuGet
Import-Module : The specified module 'NuGet' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module NuGet
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (NuGet:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question. Has your issue made any progress?

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework does not actually implement HTTP/2, which is a requirement of the gRPC protocol. Therefore, the .NET Framework has limited support for gRPC based on HTTP/2.

It seems that you performed the above operations in the WinForms (.net framework) project. Similarly, I encountered a similar situation to yours in the Winforms (.net framework) project. gRPC Tools did not appear in the project references after being successfully added.

But in Winforms (referring to .net-based Winforms), gRPC Tools can be successfully added to the reference. You can use Winforms based on .net to perform corresponding operations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For details, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/supported-platforms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-grpc-client-requirements

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/netstandard?view=aspnetcore-6.0#net-framework

Answer (score 0):

For the client side with gRPC in C# you should be using the [Grpc.Net.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Net.Client/) package (and for the server side the [Grpc.AspNetCore.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.AspNetCore.Server/) package). The `Grpc.Core` package is in a [maintenance mode](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/) and will not be used anymore. However, as @wenbingeng-MSFT pointed out in his answer, using the `Grpc.Net.Client` package is not a good idea if you are having problems with the HTTP/2 protocol implementation of gRPC.